# SqlException & Timer Job

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I found the below ULS Log entries, Timer job (OWSTimer.EXE) is causing this however would like to know the name of the Timer-job, how can i achieve this? (without enabling verbose logging)

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections.
>
> SqlError: 'A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL
>   Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: TCP Provider,
>   error: 0 - The wait operation timed
>   out.)'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data
>   Provider' Number: 258 State: 0 Class:
>   20 Procedure: '' LineNumber: 0 Server:
>   ''

Comment: What version of SharePoint?  What level of logging do you have today?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a tool like wireshark to see what kind of network traffic is being generated and under which account a request and to which SQL box is being made. I suspect this error is triggered one of the following ways (first 2 unlikely ones, then the likely problem):

- *Not likely*: a security issue, sql is inaccessible to the account the call is made under, maybe originating from a timerjob that uses a (non sharepoint) database of it's own.
- *Not likely*: a (non sharepoint) database used by a timerjob doesn't exist anymore, or the sql box it was running on is unreachable.
- *Very likely*, a webapp is running using either the local service or the network service account (or any other local user). Code in timerjobs etc. bound to that webapp might use that account. If it is a local account, it won't have access to a database on another machine if you haven't granted access to that account on the sql machine. And granting a local account from machine A access to machine is not something you would normally do (I hope).